# Can't Edit Specific Note Using Laravel and Modal Popup

Tags: laravel

I am working on a Laravel application where I have implemented a feature to edit notes. Each note has a unique ID stored in the database. However, I am facing an issue where only the first note on the profile is being edited, regardless of which note I select for editing.

Controller

```
public function saveEdits(Request $request, $note_id)
{
    $noteContent = $request->input('note_content');
    $noteinfo = notes::findOrFail($note_id);

    if (!$noteinfo) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Note not found!'], 404);
    }

    if ($noteinfo) {
        $noteinfo->note = $noteContent;
        $noteinfo->save();
        session()->flash('notification', ['type' => 'success', 'message' => 'Note updated  successfully']);
    } else {
        session()->flash('notification', ['type' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error In updating note']);

    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Modal (profile.blade.php)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="noteModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Notes</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="POST" id="saveEditsForm" name = "saveEditsForm" action="{{ route('saveEdits', ['note_id' => $note->note_id]) }}">
                @method('PUT')
                    @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" name="note_id" value="{{ $note->note_id }}">
                    <textarea name="note_content" id="noteContent" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control bg-transparent" title="Please edit your note" required></textarea>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Route

```
Route::put('saveEdits/{note_id}', [NotesController::class, 'saveEdits']) -> name('saveEdits');
```

Comment: Hi @Angelo, Can you `dd($note_id);` inside `saveEdits` and check the value you are getting for the `$note_id` ?

Comment: @SujithSandeep after dd($note_id);  i see 56. but the note, I'm trying to edit has an id of 57. however 56 is the first note on the profile

Comment: Then the problem is not with `saveEdits` function. In `profile.blade.php`, Can you check the `textarea` data which you are trying to update is of data with id `57` ?

Comment: @SujithSandeep this is my textarea
<textarea name="note_content" id="noteContent" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control bg-transparent" title="Please edit your note" required></textarea>

Comment: I am asking whether you are getting proper values to edit in that textarea. i.e.., Data related to id 57 ?

Comment: @SujithSandeep yes, when it comes to clicking to edit button to open and edit the note in the textarea it works fine with the correct note id and correct note but the issues is with saving the edited note. it overwrites and save on the first note and not the targeted note

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display multiple modals for each note using a loop, you can add a unique identifier to the id attribute of the modal div. To achieve this, you can concatenate the $note->note_id value with the string 'noteModal' in the id attribute.
your code should look something like this :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="noteModal{{$note->note_id}}">
```

and your edit button you should add

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' date-toggle='modal' data-target="#noteModal{{$note->note_id}}">edit<button>
```

i hope this helps